# checking swift version shows requested but did not find extenstion

Tags: swift, xcode

so running simple command `swift --version`
shows next text in the console

```
2022-08-31 09:42:15.776 xcodebuild[4154:82946] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-08-31 09:42:15.776 xcodebuild[4154:82946] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-08-31 09:42:16.615 xcodebuild[4155:82963] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-08-31 09:42:16.615 xcodebuild[4155:82963] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
swift-driver version: 1.45.2 Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx12.0
```

What should I do to fix it? ( not to show requested bud did not find exteions point..) only the line with version

More context:
I am on macbook pro m1 chip
I have two xcode 13.4.1 and beta  14.0 beta 5